# How to concat css files with images and fonts form Bower in Grunt/Gulp/Webpack

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, gulp, webpack

I have a project with some bower components.
Head of my `index.html` looks like:

> ```
> <link href="js/vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
> <link href="js/vendors/jquery-ui-custom/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
> ```

I want to minify and concat stylesheets.
Is there solution to concat all css files in one bundle and copy images/fonts in new directory with new `bundle.css` file?

I found npm `grunt-concat-css` but seems it only concat files and I have to use some copy tasks for copy images and fonts to new directory.

Comment: You might want to get your vendor scripts from a CDN rather than bundling them with your site's CSS.

Comment: What if I have many vendors scipts? I think it should be minify and gzipped.

Comment: They'll be minified and gzipped from a CDN though, and it frees up connections to your server. Plus if its a popular library (like jQuery) the user may already have it cached in their browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gulp I use npm's [wiredep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep) so that my bower dependencies are automatically managed for me.

I DO concatenate and uglify vendor js and css myself. I do so using [useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref) which works like a charm.

Also, you can use [inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject) so that your own dependencies are automatically maintained by gulp.

Note: If you decide to wiredep you can call your gulp task from bower on every install/uninstall. That way you never... ever... have to think about your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gulp-concat-css` as:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css');
var files = [
'js/vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
'js/vendors/jquery-ui-custom/jquery-ui.css',
'css/main.css'
];

gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src(files)
    .pipe(concatCss("bundle.css"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('out/'));
});
```